# SDL2 programme crashes using events

Tags: c++, input, sdl-2

I have a problem with crashing my programme when handling events in SDL2.

I handle events like this:

```
const Uint8 *key_buttons;

SDL_Event e;

while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
{
  switch(e.type)
  {
    case SDL_QUIT:
      running = false;
      break;

    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
      key_buttons = SDL_GetKeyboardState(0);
      break;   

    case SDL_KEYUP:
      key_buttons = SDL_GetKeyboardState(0);
      break; 
  }
}
```

And then, when I call this function:

```
bool Get_KeyButtonState(SDL_Scancode key)
{
  if (!key_buttons)
    return false;

  if (key_buttons[key])
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

My programme crashes.

If I call `SDL_GetKeyboardState()` at start of the while loop and stop using `SDL_KEYDOWN` and `SDL_KEYUP`, then my programme works.

So, my question is: **why it happens and what's the proper solution?** And also, is there a way how to handle just change of a state without needing to save previous state of all buttons (cause I couldn't find any function for this)?

Comment: I know nothing about SDL, and yet that program looks highly suspect.  You have an uninitialized pointer, so accessing `key_buttons` without initializing it is undefined behavior.  That means that your attempt of removing those two mouse cases results in undefined behavior.  Second, how can you guarantee that `key_buttons` has at least `key + 1` entries?  You just assume it does without testing for it?

Comment: Thank you! You were right, I forget to initialize the key_buttons, now it seems everything works properly (the evil C++).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just giving an initial NULL:

```cpp
const Uint8 *key_buttons = NULL; // or 0
```

This ensure that your `if (!key_buttons) return false;` will work in all cases.

BTW, the `const` is confusing. In this case, it means the "value that the pointer points to" is immutable, but the "pointer itself" is mutable.

- In case you are interested in more about "const", please read [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const).